# Prisma, know which entity is called

Tags: prisma

In Prisma ORM, if I have

```
prisma.user
```

There's a way to know that the entity I'm using is user?

Comment: Can you please elaborate?

Comment: I need to pass to a function prisma.user, or prisma.work. Inside the function depending of which one is passed, some code has to execute. So, how can I know it. I want to avoid to pass two parameters, for example prisma.user, 'user'

Answer (score 0):

You can use Function's [name](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/name) argument to determine which function is being invoked and can determine the model name from it.

Example:

```js
const functionName = prisma.user.aggregate.name;
console.log('functionName:',functionName);
const modelName = functionName.split('.')[1];
console.log('modelName:',modelName);
```

Output:

```js
functionName:prisma.user
modelName:user
```

From the output you can get your model name i.e `user` after getting the part of the string after (.)

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't work. Those aren't functions, are interfaces.